# Plymouth themes

Tags: 11.10, gtk3

Ola pessoal eu sou novato em linux mais ja entendo muita coisa quero aprender a custumizar uma distro deste a interface ao mais além.

mais o que me traz aqui é o seguinte quais são os passo que eu devo seguir para desenvolver um tema com plymouth e gtk
criar os meus proprios Usplash, boot splash personalizar as cores das janelas e alterar o lightDM

outro ponto que linguagem de programação eu devo saber para se adpatar melhor?

Hello guys I'm new to linux already understand a lot more I want to learn this distro customiser an interface to the beyond.

More of what brings me here is the following. What are the steps I should follow to develop a theme with gtk plymouth and create my own usplash, boot splash customize the colors of the windows and change the lightDM?

Another point which programming language should I learn to adapt better?

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools to use to customise the splash screen, backgrounds, edit plymouth etc.

One of the most useful is "Burg" grub customiser.

To install Grub Customizer. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

There is a tutorial listed [here](http://jechem.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-grub-customizer-for-ubuntu.html)